# What is the difference between using href and Link in React JS

Tags: reactjs

what is the difference between LINK

```
<Link to="/login" className="header">Sign In </Link>
```

and using the href in React JS

```
<a href={url}>Sign In </a>
```

what is the main difference between using these in React JS

Comment: href is window object. Link is wrapper of react router. Under the hood, its doing window object thing. But it can help you track state, prevProps and move from one route to another without reloading page

Comment: href is standard HTML. <Link> is a component from a library that you haven't mentioned that's described in the library's documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Two points:

**First**,  is a traditional way to do link, that is **NOT** using **[History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)**, each click will navigate the whole page. thus hard to do SPA, etc., in contract, `<Link>` can do SPA, and won't trigger a page refresh.

**Second**, besides using [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API), in [React Router V3](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/v3), A  can **know when the route it links to is active and automatically apply an activeClassName** and/or activeStyle when given either prop. The  will be active if the current route is either the linked route or any descendant of the linked route. In contract, `<a href>` cannot.

From [React Router V4](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/v4.0.0), the above feature roughly splited into  and .